# Pull Information From Facebook

Tags: facebook

How can I pull information from MY profile on Facebook and display it on the website I am developing?

I know I can open a dialog to request login to Facebook, but I don't want to login any user. I want to login MY account and get MY info.

Is for contact card purposes.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a [badge](https://www.facebook.com/badges/) of some kind?

Comment: No, I wanna pull information from Facebook and post it on my personal website. No predefined stuff, I want to display the information in my own layout.

Comment: Maybe you should be more specific. What information do you want to "pull" from Facebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could generate an access token, with offline_access and all the other perms you need, and save that with your uid on your server somewhere. Then make a server request to FB for the data when you need it, cache it, and display it?

Comment: This is almost certainly the best/only way